# How to resolve DataGrid Type in .Net Core 3.x WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I'm in the process of converting a legacy WinForms app to .Net Core 3.  This is the 2nd Winform's App I'm converting, I had success converting the first one.

The challenge I'm hitting is that this WinForms app uses the `DataGrid` control and the compiler is complaining:

> The type or namespace 'DataGrid' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This can also be seen by hovering over the type in VS.  I'm using Visual Studio 16.4.2, although I'm not sure that matters.

[image]

Ctl+. does not provide any nuget packages to resolve this type.  My WinForms project contains `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` and all the other WinFroms types resolve no problem, eg. `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`.

I'm a bit baffled that `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` is an "unknown type".  Any help on how to resolve this type would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They decided not to port the .NET 1.0 classes that were replaced in .NET 2.0.  DataGrid was replaced by DataGridView.

Comment: ^ [This post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms-breaking-changes) explains more

Comment: @HansPassant3 Gotcha.  Provide that as the answer and I'll accept it. Guess I'm off to learn how to port the `DataGrid` code to a `DataGridView` :-)

Comment: Shouldn't be that difficult.  DataGridView is a better control anyway.

Comment: This may help as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/differences-between-the-windows-forms-datagridview-and-datagrid-controls

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed.  If they replaced the control the new one is probably a much better control.

Comment: As a curiosity, [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid) that it's available in both .Net Core 3.0 and 3.1

Comment: @Jimi I saw that too. That documentation seems to be in direct contradiction to  the post devNull (above) pointed out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms-breaking-changes and of course the compiler doesn't lie. :-)  So looks like MS has some docs cleanup to do.

Comment: For those following along, in my case, getting the code to compile was almost as easy as swapping out all occurrences of `DataGrid`  to `DataGridView`.  I only had one property on it I was using that didn't port straight across, that was DataGrid's `HeaderForeColor` and I just commented out that line of code.  So I'm quite happy.